# How can I show the sorting progress step by step on output screen?

Tags: pascal

I don't know how to make sorting process visible on output.. (like you can see the step by step of each sorting phase on output).

Below is example of a similar program.
[image: example]

And here's my current progress:

```
program insertsort;
const 
  max = 100;

type 
  arr = array [1..max] of integer;

var
  data : arr;
  n, i, j : integer;

  procedure InsertionSort(size : integer);
  var 
    i, j, index : integer;

  begin
    for i := 2 to size do
    begin
      index := data[i];
      j := i;

      while ((j > 1) and (data[j-1] < index)) do
      begin
         data[j] := data[j-1];
         j := j - 1;
      end;

      data[j] := index;
    end;

  end;
   
begin
  write('Input Data : '); 
  readln(n);

  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    write ('Data-',i,' = '); readln(data[i]);
  end;
  
  writeln;
  write ('Unsorted : ');
     
  for i := 1 to n do
    write(data[i],' ');

  InsertionSort(max);

  writeln;
  writeln;
  writeln;
  write('Sorted : ');
    
  for i := 1 to n do
    write(data[i],' '); 

  readln;

end.
```

Comment: Add a loop to display the values in the `data` array, immediately after `data[j] := index;` within the `InsertionSort()` procedure.

Comment: oh, you're right. Thanks